# Grid system does not work when it is inside a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, grid

I am using the [Salvattore](https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore) plugin to create a grid based layout for my website.

Here is how the plugin should set up in HTML:

```
<div class="grid columns2" data-columns>
  <img src="">
  <img src="">
</div>
```

It basically finds `.grid` and then `.columns3` which determines how many columns the plugin should create inside `.grid`.

The outcome would look like:

```
<div class="grid" data-columns="2">
    <div class="column count-2">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="column count-2">
      <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

All works fine, until the `.grid` is a child of a parent which has `display: hidden` - i.e:

```
<div style="display:none" id="popup">
  <div class="grid" data-columns="2">
     <div class="column count-2">
        <img src="">
     </div>
    <div class="column count-2">
       <img src="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why I gave it display: none? well, I am trying to use this .grid inside div's which are hidden by default and only show when requested, for example, inside a popup window or UI accordion and tabs.

I have created a live test here: [http://loai.directory/beta](http://loai.directory/beta/) if you look, you will see two containers with the `.grid` one that works fine and the other one below where it says *The hidden div is below me* which is the one in question.

**Here is what I thought of doing** "but don't have the skills to try it or even know where to start" - I was wondering, would the problem be solved if using JavaScript to trigger the plugin again each time the .grid state changes?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with Salvatore's plugin is in grid-system.js (ln. 538)

```
self.registerGrid = function registerGrid (grid) {
    if (global.getComputedStyle(grid).display === "none") {
        return; // so basically any class or inline style with display set to none :s
    }
    /*...*/
};
```

To workaround this issue, you can bind an unique event to it's "toggle/display" trigger. It would be ideal that all triggers and hidden layers, match an unique id or some commonly mapped reference.

```
<a href="#" data-ref="popup">trigger popup</a>
<div id="popup" class="grid hide" data-columns></div>
```

Then the js would be something like:

```
function delayedGrid() {
    var grids = $('.grid.hide[data-columns]'); // assuming they all have the hide class
    // var grids = $('.grid:hidden'); // could work as well

    $.each(grids, function(){
        // pickup the mapped references from your grid (id and ref)
        var grid = $(this),
            id = grid.prop('id'), // get the id reference
            ref = $('[data-ref="' + id + '"]'); // get the referenced element by data-ref="popup" for ex.

        // one time only event
        ref.one('click', function() {
            // gives browser reflow a better chance
            setTimeout(function() {
                // call the grid initializer again
                salvattore.init();
            }, 200);
        });
    });
}
```

Then all you need to do is render `delayedGrid` on DOM ready, or onload, or on resize, or whenever you need to recalculate your hidden grids.

```
// DOM ready
$(fuction(){
    delayedGrid();
});

// window load
$(window).load(function(){
    delayedGrid();
});

// window resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    // google for throttle function perhaps
    delayedGrid();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Tim. I am not sure how to get your method working, so it will trigger the plugin again on click? click on where? thank you again!

Comment: Yes that's the question, how do you trigger your popup? btn (click), link (click), event (load, resize), ...
In any case, combine the event handler with the `delayedGrid` and that should do the trick.

Comment: Can we make it run on load? please can you show me how?

Comment: Added some comments and changed the html/jquery selectors a bit. if it doesn't work out, update your beta test or use jsfiddle or something and I'll have a look.